# sorting a list by a certain letter and by alphabetical order

Tags: list, sorting, alphabetical

#### START FUNCTION

def front_x(words):
    # your code here

```
return
```

#### END FUNCTION

Given a list of strings, I want to return a list with the strings in sorted order, except group all the strings that begin with 'x' first. I know I might need to sort the list by words starting with 'x' then by alphabet, i just cannot return the code. im still pretty fresh at this.

Comment: This looks like homework question

Answer (score 0):

In the future try to formulate your question better and put the language tag

here is a direct way to do your task (its' not necessarly optimized)

```py
def front_x(words): # your code here
  words_starting_with_x=[]
  words_not_starting_with_x=[]
  for word in words:
    if word[0]== "x":
      words_starting_with_x.append(word)
    else:
      words_not_starting_with_x.append(word)
  words_starting_with_x = sorted(words_starting_with_x)   # there 
  words_not_starting_with_x = sorted(words_not_starting_with_x)

  return words_starting_with_x + words_not_starting_with_x  #+ operator does the concatenation for list

my_list=["hope_you_got_it!","x4_place","x2_is_not","x3_a","x5_to_do","x6_your","x7_exercises","x1_stackoverflow","some_other_words_bla_bla"]
front_x(my_list)
```

and the output is:

```py
['x1_stackoverflow',
 'x2_is_not',
 'x3_a',
 'x4_place',
 'x5_to_do',
 'x6_your',
 'x7_exercises',
 'hope_you_got_it!',
 'some_other_words_bla_bla']
```